# Max, min or saddle point?

Tags: maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

Consider the function on $\mathbb{R}^2$:
\begin{equation*}
V(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)^2-a(x^2+y^2)+a^2/4
\end{equation*}
with $a$ real. I want to decide weather the critical points are max, min or saddle points.

We can see that the point $(0,0)$ and the points on the circumference $x^2+y^2 = \frac{a}{2}$ are critical points. If we calculate the hessian matrix we have
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{H} 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
4(3x^2+y^2)-2a & 8xy \\
8xy & 4(x^2+3y^2)-2a \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\det \mathcal{H} = 16 \cdot \left[ 3 (x^2+y^2)^2-2a(x^2+y^2)+\frac{a^2}{4} \right]
\end{equation*}
Then $\det \mathcal{H}_{(0,0)} = 4a^2$ so the point $(0,0)$ is max if $a>0$ and min if $a<0$. And by deduction a min for $a=0$.

How can I decide the point on the circumference $x^2+y^2 = \frac{a}{2}$?

Comment: Compute the eigenvalues of $H$ instead of just the determinant. This will give you more detailed information.

Comment: And what can I do with that?

Comment: A positive eigenvalue corresponds to a direction along which you have a minimum; a zero eigenvalue a direction along which the function is constant; a negative eigenvalue a direction along which the function has a maximum. Try it.

Comment: Did you observe that $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2-a/2)^2$?

Comment: yes, but for the points on the circumference I get $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_2=4a$, so I have one eigenvalue equal to zero. That means I get flatness on the points? @Marcel

Comment: @Spectree Yes. The function is circular symmetric, and it is flat in the $\theta$ direction at the critical radius. It is a minimum in the radial direction, if $a>0$.